# Load work to background thread

Tags: c#

I got a method, which downloads files from a server. This works so far, but my UI freezes as long as the dl is in progress. Here is my method:

```
private void DownloadHandler()
{ 
  foreach (var file in SelectedFiles.ToList())
  {
    var data = new FileData(file.Name, DataType.MeasurementData, SelectedDirectory.Name);

    int rc = mFileService.DownloadMeasurementFile(data, SelectedFolderPath, true);

    if (rc != 0)
    {
      //log error
      LoggerFactory.Logger.Error("Download file failed!");
      ...
    }     
  }     
}
```

All I want to achieve is prevent my UI from freezing, my app wont get a performance boost by parallelizing the dl, because the bottleneck is the download rate.

So I tried:

```
 private void DownloadHandler()
{    
  foreach (var file in SelectedFiles.ToList())
  {
    var data = new FileData(file.Name, DataType.MeasurementData, SelectedDirectory.Name);

    var task = Task.Run(() => mFileService.DownloadMeasurementFile(data, SelectedFolderPath, true));
    task.ContinueWith(
      t =>
      {
        if (t.Result != 0)
        {
          //log error
          LoggerFactory.Logger.Error("Download file failed!");        
          ...             
        }   
      });
  }    
}
```

And added a lock in my `DownloadMeasurementFile` method. This should let my app call the `DownloadHandler` and return immediately (this part works). After that (in my opinion) it should behave just like the sync version, because of the lock inside `DownloadMeasurementFile` method. But in fact this will mess up my download calls to the server, I dont understand whats exactly going wrong right now but the server returns empty chunks of data and has other problems when it shouldnt.

So can anybody tell me what I'm missing? It shouldnt be so hard so send the work of the `DownloadHandler` to a background thread, lock right afterwards to sync the call and keep the UI from freezing?

EDIT:

as mentioned in comments I moved all download code into a new method and started a task just calling this method.

```
 private void DownloadHandler()
{
  var task = Task.Run(() => { Foo(); });
}

private void Foo()
{
  IsLoading = true;
  foreach (var file in SelectedFiles.ToList())
  {
    var data = new FileData(file.Name, DataType.MeasurementData, SelectedDirectory.Name);

    int rc = mFileService.DownloadMeasurementFile(data, SelectedFolderPath, true);

    if (rc != 0)
    {
      //log error
      LoggerFactory.Logger.Error("Download file failed!");
    }
    else
    {
      if (!file.IsDownloaded(SelectedFolderPath))
      {
        // log error
      }
    }
    // refresh instead?
    RaiseBeginUpdate();
    Files.Remove(file);
    RaiseEndUpdate();
  }
  IsLoading = false;
}
```

This works just fine.

Comment: i think you need to add the code for "DownloadMeasurementFile". Generally I would make the task to be for the full "downlloadhandler()" method instead of having it inside the foreach, this will be more similar to what you had before, and downloading files will be done one after another.

Comment: @AKhudairy `DownloadMeasurementFile` should not be of any interest, why do you think you need to see it?

Comment: @AKhudairy check my edit... but I dont really understand what is the difference yet.

Comment: use async / await

Comment: @user3292642 was ur problem solved after the edit? I am still not sure what i sgoing on inside "DownloadMeasurementFile", because you might be using some shared variables which will go messy when all download threads start at once.

Comment: @AKhudairy yes it is solved after that. `DownloadMeasurementFile` might go messy when parallelizing because of shared variables or anything else, but as I stated in the opening post, I just want the files to be downloaded one after another (parallelizing wont increase perfomance here).

Comment: @Unlockedluca your comment just doesn't make any sense. You don't know whats going on inside `DownloadMeasurementFile` and thus cannot know whether using async/await does make sense or not.